# Serilization in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I want to understand of functionality of the `Serializable`

Why should I use this word in my class definition?

I have this code example for it:

```
public class Paging implements Serializable {


}
```

Comment: [Click me!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: @aroun clicking you just takes me to your user page...:-P

Comment: @Pureferret That's also an answer, usually I have that inspiration on people.. Just when they visit my profile, they know all answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter better answered by the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun  I don't like the wording of that close reason because it starts *"Questions asking for code.."* and is applied to many questions that **don't** ask for code, but should be closed for much the same reason.  Just a thought.  I might take it up on Meta if I find the time/motivation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your'e definitely right. I'll be waiting the post there :)

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun  Ugg..  I should have known it has already been [discussed extensively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185142/155831)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Marker Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and  just  like an normal `interface.` with no methods.

```
 public class Paging implements Serializable{

  }
```

And somewhere else `Runtime` realizes objects like

```
if (Paging instanceof Serializable) {
        // Hey this object is able to serialize..lets go furthur
    } else {
        // Dear programmer , your class not implemented Serializable
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Serializable` interface forces no methods to implement since it is a **marker interface**.
Read about marker interfaces to understand better what it does.

Answer (score 1):

`Serializable` is a *Marker* interface. If you want to serialize and deserialize the state of your object. then, you need to implement this interface to let the JVM know that it can be serialized and deserialized

Answer (score 1):

Serializable is a "**marker interface**"(which is used to tag a class for a specific feature). Here, a class whose objects which needs to be serialized/deserialized have to implement this interface. During serialization/de-serialization process, the JVM checks whether the object is an instance of Serializable else it will throw an expection informing that the object can't be serialized/deserialized.

Hope the above explanation may help you. If it is helpful for you, then vote for me

~Ragesh