# Why Serializable interface does not contain methods or fields in java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

So my question is, why serializable interface does not contain methods or fields?

When we can use Serializable interface?

What happen during deserialization?

Comment: It's a marker interface. Read the javadoc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015649/serilization-in-java ????

Answer (score 0):

Serializable interface is a "**Marker**"or "**Tagging**" interface. Whenever a class implements the serializable interface, that class is "marked" as serializable and the objects of the class are given that property.

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` interface is termed as 'Marker' interface. This interface has been created to let `JVM` know that these `Object` types are allowed to be serialized and deserialized. You would have directly read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) instead of posting this question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

1) Java serialization does not need any methods.

2) You can use Serializable when you create a new class and you want it to be serializable

3) During serialization object class descriptors and then object fields are sent to a stream.

Details are here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html